# Email not working on Plesk server

Tags: php, email, plesk, plesk-onyx

I am using Plesk GoDaddy server to send emails to the user. I have tried this is simple mail PHP function to send email but it gives me this error.

[image]

This is my code I have tried.

```
<?php

    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $name = $_POST['email'];
        $from = "info@site.ir";
        $to = 'si87841@gmail.com';  
        $subject = 'Test Sending';
        $message = 'You got a message from '. $name;
        $headers = array(
            'MIME-Version: 1.0',
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit',
            'Date: ' . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']),
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from
        );
        $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\n", $headers));

       echo "this is mail sent---> " . $mailsent;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Script itself is working. There is something wrong with environment you have. 
Verify that simple PHP scripts are working, like

```
<?php
echo "Test Script";
?>
```

As far as I understand, you are running Plesk on Windows. Enable detailed report in IIS > Sites > domain_name > Error pages > Edit Feature Settings

[image]

And check the detailed error.

If the information is not enough, check EventViewer for error, try to enable [failed request tracing via Plesk](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/customer-account-administration/viewing-statistics/tracing-failed-requests-windows.74484/) and inspect the report.